# how to get message number that content type 's "multipart" from gmail?

Tags: java, gmail

I want to get the message number list  that the content type is "multipart".I tried using javaxmail, it works but i don't want to get the messages and then do the filter.

```
 try {
  Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(this.setPropertiesParams());
  Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");
  store.connect(host, email, emailPassword);
  Folder emailFolder;
  emailFolder = store.getFolder("Documents");      
  emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
  SearchTerm andTerm = searchMessageByDate(fromDate, toDate);      
  Message[] messages = emailFolder.search(andTerm);
  Message[] finalMessages = emailFolder.search(new SubjectTerm("Scan de votre document"), messages);   

  for (Message message : finalMessages) {
        String contentType = message.getContentType();
        if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
          Integer messageNumber = message.getMessageNumber();
          numberList.add(messageNumber);
        }
  }
  emailFolder.close(false);
  store.close();
```

How to do it. thanks for any help.

Comment: You can implement a new subclass of `SearchTerm` that does that, but the message would probably have to be fetched anyway. I don't think you can avoid it.

Comment: @MauricePerry thanks for your answer. do you have an example for implementing SearchTerm thanks in advance.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a new subclass of SearchTerm that does that, but the message would probably have to be fetched anyway. I don't think you can avoid it.

```
public class ContentTypeTerm extends SearchTerm {
    @Override
    public boolean match(Message msg) {
        try {
            return msg.isMimeType("multipart/*");
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE

You could actually use a `HeaderTerm`:

```
SearchTerm[] terms = {
        searchMessageByDate(fromDate, toDate),
        new HeaderTerm("Content-Type", "multipart/.*")
    };
SearchTerm andTerm = new AndTerm(terms);
```